# Does the order of Babel 6 presets matter?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

When I list the presets, does the order matter?

In other words, are the following `.babelrc` files equivalent?

`.babelrc` #1

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2", "react"]
}
```

`.babelrc` #2

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "stage-2", "es2015"]
}
```

Comment: Good question. I think they are expanded in order and the final list used, but I'm not sure what happens if two presets have different options for the same plugin.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618756/babel-plugins-run-order

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From [babeljs.io/docs/plugins:](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/) (as of 9/30/2016)

## Plugin/Preset Ordering

Ordering matters for each visitor in the plugin. This means if two transforms both visit “Program”, the transforms will run in either plugin or preset order.

### Plugins run before Presets.

#### Plugin ordering is first to last.

```
"plugins": [
  "transform-decorators-legacy", // will run first
  "transform-class-properties" // will run second
]
```

#### Preset ordering is reversed (last to first).

Yes this is confusing, see [babel/notes #2](https://github.com/babel/notes/blob/master/2016-08/august-01.md#potential-api-changes-for-traversal).

I believe the reason why (for backwards compatability) is that most users had listed “es2015” first and “stage-0” second. And stage-0 would run before es2015.

```
"presets": [
  "es2015", // will run third
  "react", // will run second
  "stage-2" // will run first
]
```