# Error building webpack: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

There have been a few questions like this in the past and the solutions given were to add a loader such as es2015. However I have tried adding es2015, 2016, 2017 (further ones and `babel-preset-env` gave other errors) and none of them could load this module. Other loaders in the webpack-config.js file are `react` and `stage-0`.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  * @private
|  */
| Exporter.prototype.<function-name> = async function * <function-name>() {
|     yield '';
| };
```

Here's the rule for js files:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  exclude: [
    /node_modules/
  ],
  query: {
    cacheDirectory: true,
    presets: ['es2015', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'react', 'stage-0']
  }
}
```

and the .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0", "es2016", "es2017"]
}
```

Does anyone know what loader this needs?
I am not very knowledgeable in babel, but it seems that this rule is excluding `/node-modules/` and this error is coming from a module in the project. Might be relevant.
Also relevant is that this same build is working on other computers where `"es2015", "es2016", "es2017"` have not been installed and were not added to presets in either of the files above.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime plugin

Comment: Also, the order or presets should be```presets: [ 'es2015', 'react', 'stage-3', 'stage-0']```

Comment: @dolly how do I know what the correct order is?

Comment: Sorry for late response, Preset ordering is reversed (last to first). Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620375/does-the-order-of-babel-6-presets-matter for your doubt.